# Lists in ListFragment overlapping on search

Tags: android, android-listfragment, android-cursoradapter, android-loader

I'm showing a list using ListFragment and loader and CursorAdapter. This list has a searchbox, so when user searches something, I show only those records which contain the searched string.
Now the problem I'm facing is that the originally shown list is overlapping with the list created after search i.e. the first list is coming as a background for the second list.
Here is how I handle search: every time some search text is submitted, I restart the loader using getLoaderManager().restartLoader() and in onLoadFinished(), I'm creating a new instance of the CursorAdapter.
I'm not able to figure out the reason for lists overlap issue. Please help.
(I would have liked to provide with the code but due to company policies I cannot, really sorry for that.)